# How to format Date with Jquery Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to get the date in this format YYYY/MM/DD.I am calling a webservice to get the data.The date format returned by the service in xml is fine but when i append that in js i am getting

> /Date(3257950500000)/

**Webservice**

```
  [WebMethod]
    public List<Common.Deposit.Views.DepositAccountStatementView> GetDepositAccountStatement(long accountNumberId,
        DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        return BusinessLayer.Deposit.DepositAccountStatement.GetDepositAccountStatementViews(accountNumberId,
            fromDate, toDate);
    }
```

JS

```js
if (data) {
  var div = $('#CfDataTable').empty();
  div.append(
    $("<tr class='success'><th>Tran Date</th><th>Value Date</th><th>Statement Reference</th><th>Collector</th><th>Debit</th><th>Credit</th><th>Balance</th><th>Check Number</th></tr>"));
  $(data.d).each(function(index, item) {
    div.append(
      $("<tr>")

      .append($("<td>").html(item.TranDate))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.ValueDate))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.StatementReference))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.Collector))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.Debit))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.Credit))
      .append($("<td>").html(item.Balance)));

  });
}
```

**XML**

```html
<DepositAccountStatementView>
<TranId>13018256</TranId>
<TranDate>2016-01-14T00:00:00</TranDate>
<ValueDate>2016-01-14T00:00:00</ValueDate>
<Collector>Office</Collector>
<Debit xsi:nil="true"/>
<Credit>11000</Credit>
<Balance>11000</Balance>
</DepositAccountStatementView>
```

Help Please.I am new to this.Help appreciated.spend hours couldnt get through.

Comment: show the `xml snippet`, `item.TranDate`, `item.ValueDate` regarding the dates - you claim "date format returned by the service in xml is fine" yet it is the most crucial information, and you left it out

Comment: Date formatting and jQuery `.append()` have nothing in common.

Comment: @birdspider i have updated the question sir.i have added the xml output.

Comment: Use this : $("<tr>").after($.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date()));